# Static Web App versioning with S3 and Cloudfront

Tags: angular, amazon-s3, static, amazon-cloudfront

Currently I am using S3 and CloudFront to host a static Angular App.

I want to version the app every time I made a deploy in order to ensure easy rollback (through my command line tools or automatic pipeline).

My S3 bucket would look something like this:

```
/production/v1.2
/production/v1.3
/production/v1.4
```

Next deploy will be in the folder /production/v1.5 and so on.

I want to use this strategy so that in case of rollback I just point the website to load from the old version /production/v1.4.

- My first solution to do this is update the CloudFront config Origin Path to point to the new folder, example `/production/v1.4`
- In case of rollback I just update the CloudFront config Origin Path to  `/production/v1.3`

---

The second solution instead I was thinking to have a live/ folder and have a CloudFront Origin Path pointing to the live/index.html folder in S3 and copy there the last version of my app or copy the rollback version everytime without changing CloudFront Origin Path:

```
/production/v1.2
/production/v1.3
/production/v1.4
/production/live
```

- Deploy the new version in `/production/v1.4` and `/production/live`
- In case of rollback just copy `/production/v1.3` to `/production/live`

Considering that it is not easy to update the CloudFront distrubution settings via cli and cache invalidations:

What do you recommend? Is there a better way to handle this kind of situation?

Comment: The only issue with the 2nd solution is caching. Even though you've changed the contents of the bucket, cloudfront may still be serving the old version from cache

Comment: @albanx, how did you end up solving this? I'm implementing this for the first time, and have been leaning towards the first approach, updating the origin path. But the AWS cloudfront update-distribution looks a little hairy, so I'm having second thoughts...

Comment: @CharlesO. my deploy script here https://pastebin.com/wHJ5MN3D basically is the first solution, with an extra step at, by copying the index.html from the build dir to the s3 root dir, also notice the angular build options, they define, the output dir and deploy url, that affects the index.html

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is a solution for most of you but I have already implemented this proof of concept on our production environment;

I needed to implement an content-security-policy with a nonce. There for I implemented a API gateway which serves a lambda function which contains our Index.html file and a js function to add headers (content-security-policy with a nonce)

As we still use Angularjs 1.X the index.html file links the whole application together (this probably counts for most one-page-applications). Our CSS and JS files are timestamped (in their filename) so its not being cached by cloudfront on each new deployment. If I want to roleback my application I can use Lambda's build in versioning.

Example of how you can implement an API gateway + lambda function to serve your index.html file
https://github.com/csarkosh/readme-viewer/tree/master

csarkosh explains his adventure in not so much detail in his medium post:
https://medium.com/@csarkosh/my-experience-getting-an-a-from-mozillas-observatory-tool-on-aws-f0abf12811a1

Answer (score 0):

For your requirement i have created python library which job of deployment and backup folder creation for rollback operation. Also its include CloudFront cache invalidation.

https://github.com/aviboy2006/angular-upload-s3cf